# Bash script with ncftp to download new remote files and save in new folder

Tags: bash, macos, ftp, cron

I have a remote server that receives files continuously throughout the day.  Because there are so many files coming in, the remote server has a cron job that moves the new files (about every 15 minutes or so) to their permanent resting place.  This necessitates frequent logins from me to look for new files and also means I can't simply mirror the directories.  I can't use rsync either.  My thought then is to use cron + bash + ncftp or lftp or something like that to create the directory for the day, login, compare the files, begin downloading new files and then close the connection, rinse repeat.

The remote system runs Windows, I am using a Mac.  I don't control the remote server, I merely have ftp access to the directory of the files (and not even their permanent store).

I am trying to configure a cron job (or more) that will:

1 - check sysdate and check if a local folder with current yyyy/mm/dd exists.  If not, then it will be created

2 - log into remote server and download all new files into their properly dated local folder (this should only be of concern around midnight between the time the server receives data and the last time I checked for new files)

I began with:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename $0)

#Here are some local variables:

NEW='/localdir/newfiles'
OLD='/localdir/oldfiles'
LOCAL_DIR='/localdir'

# Here are the remote server variables

HOST='some.server'
USER='user'
PASSWD='passwd'
REMOTE_DIR='/remotedir'
#Let's check for new files:

ncftpls -1 HOST > NEW #this lists files and creates a record we can use to compare with

diff OLD > NEW
????
```

However, when testing with ncftpget, I am prompted when the program identifies duplicate files, at which point I may select 'S!' and this skips all files that already exist locally.  So I am sensing that I don't need to deal with diff at all nor listing contents of both directories, thus eliminating the need for NEW and OLD and simplifying this for me with something like:

```
ncftpget *.filetype
```

EDIT: in order to grab the files in the directory, I had to use -R but because I am remoting into a Windows box, -R does not work, does this mean ncftp is not viable?  Does that necessitate lftp?

Should this work for me so long as I can somehow use S! by default?  Would this be robust enough or would the creation of files holding lists of the directory contents and comparing between them be a more sound execution?  I am worried about using up resources/bandwidth but I don't want to miss any files either.  The last concern then would be creating the folders and logging errors and it seems ncftp and the subprograms have both a standard log and an error log, if that is correct, then I really only need to worry about moving the files to the folder of the current day's date.

Maybe a more logical workflow would be to run a separate cron job at the end of every day to handle moving files downloaded that day to a folder matching that day's date.  So that cron job would have a bash script checking in LOCAL_DIR and reading the date added of each file and moving to the appropriate folder, if it does not exist, it would mkdir etc.

Thanks in advance for any insight/advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this and managed to get things in a reasonably stable situation.  I did split the two tasks into two separate bash scripts.

```
ncftpget -R -T -f "$FTP" -d "$NCFTP_LOG" "$REMOTEDIR" "*.xml"
EXIT_V="$?"
    case $EXIT_V in
        0) O="Success.";;
        1) O="Could not connect to remote host.";;
        2) O="Could not connect to remote host - timed out.";;
        3) O="Transfer failed.";;
        4) O="Transfer failed - timed out.";;
        5) O="Directory change failed.";;
        6) O="Directory change failed - timed out.";;
        7) O="Malformed URL.";;
        8) O="Usage error.";;
        9) O="Error in login configuration file.";;
        10) O="Library initialization failed.";;
        11) O="Session initialization failed.";;
    esac

if [ "$EXIT_V" = 0 ]; 
    then
        echo ""$O"! New files have been retrieved!"
    else
        echo "There has been an error: "$O""
fi
```

This works well and I built checks around the above with great success.  The second task was to archive the files daily.  Here is the pertinent snippet:

```
FILE=( $(find $REMOTEDIR -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.xxx") )

if [ "${#FILE[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then 
    rsync -aq --include='*.xxx' $REMOTEDIR/ $LOCALDIR
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
        then
            find $REMOTEDIR -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.xxx" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
            echo "All of today's files have been moved to the archive."
        else
            echo "There was an error while running rsync."
    fi
else
    echo "There are no files to be moved.  This may indicate a problem."
    echo "Check the tracelog."
    exit 1
fi
```